# Loop through range and change data

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I am looking to loop through range of around 100k rows to change data.

Let's say I have strings in Range("A1:A" & tempRows). Based on value (<> tempVal) I want to change values in corresponding cells Range("B1:B" & tempRows).

A For-Next loop with IF takes a long time.

I was thinking of arrays and changing values in one array is easy (For Each item in array) but comparing values in another array is not so easy.

How do I get array index without looping For-Next?

With the below code I get subscript out of range error:

```vb
Dim Arr(), arrEmp() as variant
arr = Range("A1:A" & tempRows).value
arrEmp = Range("B1:B" & tempRows).value
for arrI = 0 to tempRows - 1
    if arr(arrI) <> tempVal and arrEmp(arrI) = 0 then arrEmp(arrI) = 1
next
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using.  The current posting will not run due to error at 'ArrEmp)'

Comment: tempRows was there just to depict that I'm working with variable ranges. For testing purposes please just assign tempRows = 100 or sth.

Comment: freeflow said `ArrEmp)` in your first line of code which already would throw an error. Try to copy paste instead of typing code to avoid these issues (or adjust it in your actual code if this was a copy paste). Also, remember for future references that when declaring a variable, you need to use the type for each variable, i.e. `Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range` instead of `Dim rng1, rng2 As Range` since rng1 in that last situation would be a Variant variable. In this case it doesn't really matter since they're both meant to be variants, however, it's not necessary to use () to get an array.

Comment: Also, when getting the value as array, you get an array with dimensions `(1 To tempRows, 1 To 1)` so use `If arr(arrI,1) <> tempVal` (and likewise for the rest). See if you get any errors after fixing that.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry for confusion. And thank you for those hints. And what about the fastest way to change values in a 100k rows range? What would be your recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)** When you read data from a range into an array (and the range contains more that one cell), you always get a 2-dimensional array, even if you read data only from one column (or one row). The first index is the row number, the second is the column number. If you address a 2-dimensional array with only one index, you will get the *subscript out of range error*.

**b)** In VBA, arrays can start and end at any index. However, when you read data from a range, the returning array has always a lower index of 1 (for both dimensions), so your loop needs to start at 1, not at 0. Best practice is to not hardcode that index but use the functions [`LBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function) and  [`UBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)

So your code could look like

```
Dim arr() As Variant, arrEmp() As Variant
With ActiveSheet
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & tempRows).Value
    arrEmp = .Range("B1:B" & tempRows).Value
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    For row = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For col = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(row, col) <> tempVal And arrEmp(row, col) = 0 Then
                arrEmp(row, col) = 1
            End If
       Next col
    Next row
    .Range("B1:B" & tempRows).Value = arrEmp
 End With
```

Comment: Oh... so a) and b) are pretty crucial information! Much appreciate. But one more - is this the fastest way, in general, not only using arrays, to change values in a range of 100k rows? I am looking for the best solution.

Comment: Yes. This is by far the fastest (and cleanest) way.

Comment: Let me report back - in my testing file of ~50k rows, For-Each-Next solution takes 72sec, your solution with arrays takes ~1.2 sec. Not bad ;) again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Possibly even faster if you can use twinBasic, the up and coming replacement for VB6/VBA.  https://nolongerset.com/create-com-addin-with-twinbasic/